# Setting Entry point for different HTML pages

Tags: gwt

I am changing my html page by using Window.Location.replace("newURL");
now I want to set the Entrypoint class for the html page having
"newURL".

Thanks,

Aman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML content of `newURL` can simply include the `nocache.js` file for a GWT module that uses the alternate `EntryPoint`.

Alternatively, you can compile a single module with multiple `EntryPoint` types, where each `EntryPoint` checks the url of the current page to determine wether or not it should perform any action.